# Spring Data Rest CORS filter technical differences

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I ran into a problem with CORS and what appears to be preflight issues. The original problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009719/spring-boot-data-rest-cors-not-being-enabled-properly-for-options-delete).

I ran across several different methods but I'm not exactly sure of the technical differences between the 3 different methods and why they would or would not work.

**Method 1:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "POST")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**Method 3:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

My general novice understanding is that Method 1 is an "older" way (e.g. before 4.2, I'm using 4.2.5). This method did not seem to work with my CrudRepositories (which makes sense). Method 2 is a newer version that was added in 4.2 and adds support for dealing with Spring Data Rest Repositories? And Method 3 is directly working with the application servers (Tomecat's) headers?

Method 1, and 2 did not work for me. Method 1 wouldn't enable any CORS requests. Method 2 would allow GET, but no preflighted requests. Method 3 seems to work with GET and preflighted requests. If my understanding is correct, I can understand why Method 1 would not work, but I do not understand why Method 2 would not work for the preflighted requests, or how I could have made it work. I am adding a catch all for Method 2 so everything should pass.

So, what are the technical differences? Which one should I be using if I am using Spring Data Rest repositories?