# CORS in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, cors, servlet-filters, http-options-method

I have added filter as answered for question in below link

[Spring Boot Data Rest + CORS not being enabled properly for OPTIONS/DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009719/spring-boot-data-rest-cors-not-being-enabled-properly-for-options-delete/40010227)

My modified code is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.thymeleaf.util.StringUtils;


public class CorsFilterUtil implements Filter {

     final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CorsFilterUtil.class);
     private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,-_]*$");

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        String origin;
        String credentialFlag;
        if (request.getHeader("Origin") == null) {
            origin = "*";
            credentialFlag = "false";
         } else {
            origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
            credentialFlag = "true";
         }

        // need to do origin.toString() to avoid findbugs error about response splitting        
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin.toString());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", credentialFlag);
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+request.getMethod()+"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            LOGGER.info("Received OPTIONS request from origin:" + request.getHeader("Origin"));
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            String headers = StringUtils.trim(request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
            if (!PATTERN.matcher(headers).matches()) {
                throw new ServletException("Invalid value provided for 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' header");
            }
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers); // allow any headers
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

I have tried doFilter with below 2 scenarios.

```
chain.doFilter(req, res);

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

But I am getting same 403 for OPTIONS.

Please let me know what should I add to work this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to configure CORS options. Below is sample configuration to add all mappings to the Cors registry. You would fine tune with your requirements.
You can check out an example with explanations on https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ web page.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
        .allowedOrigins("*")
        .allowedHeaders("*");
  }
}
```