# Spring Boot CORS issue

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to learn spring with this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

but I am doing frontend app as a separate app.
While making a call to: http://localhost:8080/api/employees

how to enable CORS globally ? thanks!

Tried in Application with:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configurer()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer()
        {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
            {
                registry.addMapping("/api/*").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000");
            }
        };
    }
```

but it does not help

did some testing with custom @RestController like here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#global-cors-configuration
and calling http://localhost:8080/api/greeting from external frontend app works fine, only those rest endpoints CRUD auto generated via spring are not allowed CORS there..
How to avoid this issue ?

Comment: didn't get your question / problem? `from external frontend app works fine, only those rest endpoints CRUD auto generated via spring are not allowed CORS there.. How to avoid this issue ?`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your main application class file:

```
    @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*"since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.
"

Comment: This answer was correct until the last version of spring boot. From now on you can't use allow credentials set to true and allowrd origin with wildcard.

Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060750/cors-error-when-using-corsfilter-and-spring-security

Comment: addAllowedOriginPattern("*") worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Note this is a very simple CORS filter that is wide open.
 * This would need to be locked down.
 * Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565438/no-access-control-allow-origin-error-with-spring-restful-hosted-in-pivotal-web
 */
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

helped

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .maxAge(3600L)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```