# Cors Error when using CorsFilter and spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building an API Service using Spring Boot. It uses Basic Auth for the authentication. When clients try to connect to the API, they will get **CORS error**.

On the Spring Boot, it throws error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true,
> allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*"since that cannot
> be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow
> credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider
> using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.

I have tried to find the example of **allowedOriginPatterns** usage but not found yet. Even for its document -https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html#allowedOriginPatterns-java.lang.String... I still don't know what is the pattern I have to put inside **config.allowedOriginPatterns();**

Below is my CorsFilter code,

```
@Configuration
public class RequestCorsFilter {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "responseType", "Authorization"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }      

}
```

And here is my Authentication code,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthenConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth
    .inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("thor").password("{noop}P@ssw00rd")
    .authorities("USER");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/v2/api-docs", 
            "/swagger-resources/**", 
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security", 
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
        };

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll() // whitelist URL permitted
            .antMatchers("/api").authenticated(); // others need auth
    }

}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `config.setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")` instead of `config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));`

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. But you have a typo,  `setAllowedOriginPatterns` takes `List` as a param. You probably meant 'setAllowedOriginPattern' instead (singular form) or they have changed it in a newer version.

Comment: ```setAllowedOriginPatterns``` accepts a ```String``` parameter as well. I didn't find the singular form ```setAllowedOriginPattern``` you were referring to.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#addAllowedOriginPattern-java.lang.String-) (and my code as well) this method has singular and plurar form. Either way, it's worth mentioning if someone else is facing with the same problem. Maybe we are referring to the different versions?

Comment: According to the documentation you provided, there are no ```setAllowedOriginPattern``` in singular but an ADD pattern ```addAllowedOriginPattern```. I think you misread the name.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, but I still can't find `setAllowedOriginPatterns` that accepts a `String` as a param. But `config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("*"))` works properly.

Comment: Outstanding, this worked for me as well migrating from 2.3.1.RELEASE to 2.5.6!

Comment: it's perfect, many thanks

Comment: In case you're using a YAML configuration file, you should use: `allowed-origin-patterns: "*"` (or `allowedOriginPatterns: "*"`)

Comment: In latest version of spring  addAllowedOriginPattern() internally add one pattern to setAllowedOriginPatterns() which expects a list. You can  use that.

Answer (score 8):

```java
config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
```

This line has to be changed. You should list all servers, that should have access to your application.

E.g. you use angular, so the development server for the frontend is http://localhost:4200. Your server in production is https://you.server.domain.com

Then your config List should look like this

```java
config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200","https://you.server.domain.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

if project use port 4000, yml config

```
allowedOrigins:
  - "http://localhost:4000"
```

http://localhost:4000 replace *
spring document:https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#cors-configuration

Answer (score 0):

There is a fully sample that works fine for me.

```
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTION"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This cannot set to true when you want to have the wildcard "*" in your origin.

```
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
```

So just remove it

Answer (score -1):

Q:allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value since that cannot

this can help for to resolve the issue :https://chowdera.com/2022/03/202203082045152102.html

terms of settlement
Cross domain configuration error , take .allowedOrigins Replace with .allowedOriginPatterns that will do .
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

```
private CorsConfiguration buildConfig() {

    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    //corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    //  Cross domain configuration error , take .allowedOrigins Replace with .allowedOriginPatterns that will do .
    //  Set the domain name that allows cross domain requests 
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    //  Set allowed methods 
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    //  Whether to allow certificates 
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    //  Cross domain allow time 
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    return corsConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", buildConfig());
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

}
class:If through the realization of WebMvcConfigurer The form of the interface , Modify as follows ：
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
/** *  Turn on cross domain  */
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    //  Set routes that allow cross domain routing 
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            //  Set the domain name that allows cross domain requests 
            //.allowedOrigins("*")  
            // Cross domain configuration error , take .allowedOrigins Replace with .allowedOriginPatterns that will do .
            .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
            //  Whether to allow certificates （cookies）
            .allowCredentials(true)
            //  Set allowed methods 
            .allowedMethods("*")
            //  Cross domain allow time 
            .maxAge(3600);
}
```

}